# how to change the disqus language into chinese?

Tags: wordpress, disqus

There is an question related to this topic in the community, but the answer there doesn't work now. and since i can't comment that question, i have to earn reputation first.....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var disqus_config = function () { 
  this.language = "ar";
};
</script>
```

this doesn't work.

and installing the disqus language plugin doesn't work. I have tried disqus language plugin. So, is there any method to to let the disqus system use the default wordpress language?

Answer (score 0):

A similar problem occured to couple of people that have posted in Stackoverflow. The solution that worked for them is going to admin/settings in the disqus portal, and then in the General table you have to disable the checkbox (uncheck) with the label "Enable Disqus 2012 features for your site", and then save the settings. There are some bugs with the language packages with the newest version.